# Does somebody know the typeface BREAD AND BUTTER Type that the Life Magazine used?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

The font for the headlines and the “bread-and-butter type”… it would be awesome, if there's somebody, some design historian expert who knows it.

[Here's a (bad) PDF](https://books.google.de/books?id=P0EEAAAAMBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) to look at: Page 10 for example.

Similar font suggestions are also very welcome.

My tip for the headline is Franklin Gothic Condensed, but it doesn't fit perfectly.

Comment: Folio Condensed perhaps? https://fontsinuse.com/tags/2707/life-magazine or.. https://www.grillitype.com/blog/in-use/content-object-life-magazine

Comment: Wrong period. Folio didn't come out until the 1950s.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's [Alternate Gothic No. 1](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/alternate-gothic-lt/). It certainly looks like one of the ATF Gothics. There were a ton of adaptations of them by different typesetting machine manufacturers, Linotype, Intertype, Monotype, Ludlow, and these would have slight differences from size to size, so don't expect any digital version to match metal type perfectly. But Alternate Gothic No. 1 looks right to me.